# Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because the return value of "java.lang.Class.getResource(String)" is null?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

```
 imageCol.setCellFactory(param -> {
        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setFitHeight(30);
        imageView.setFitWidth(30);
        TableCell<Product, Image> cell = new TableCell<Product, Image>(){
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Image item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (!empty){
                    System.out.println(getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()).getProductName());
                    String filePath = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()).getImagePath();
                    if (filePath.equals(" ")){
                        filePath = "imgs/TRADAO.png";
                    }
                    String url = (Main.class.getResource(filePath)).toExternalForm();
                    imageView.setImage(new Image(url));
                    setGraphic(imageView);
                }
                else setGraphic(null);
            }
        };
        return cell;
```

I want to place an image into my sales system, but it's throwing a null error. It was working fine the day before, and the code was running as expected. However, today, when I reopened it, the code is giving an error.

How can I fix it? I've researched, and people suggest creating an 'imgs' directory. I did that, but it still gives a null error. What should I do

Comment: Edit your question and include your code as text, not as an image.  Also, the argument passed to getResource is *not* a file path.  It is a relative URL, resolved against the location of the class on which it is invoked.

Comment: how can i fix this URL ?? :(((

Comment: As [the documentation explains](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)), the resource location is relative to your class.  If your class is in the package `com.example`, there must exist a `com/example/imgs/TRADAO.png` in the .jar file from which your program is running.